# Outlook 2007/2010 adding space inside table cell

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I'm building a responsive newsletter which display correctly in every browsers and email clients except Outlook 2007 & 2010 (though it's ok on Outlook 2003 and previous, and on 2013 and upper versions).

There is an extra 18px space added inside one of the table cells of this header:

[image]

With some explanations:

[image]

**1** is a a table inside my first cell, which seems to have the valid height (186px). **2** and **3** pictures are 186px height, but their cells are bigger.

Here is the header html:

```
<tr>
  <td align="left" valign="top">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse !important; background-color:#ffffff;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
      <tr>
        <td width="225" height="186" bgcolor="#7c64a9" class="nd-bandeau-cell1" style="background-color: #7c64a9">
          <table width="100%" align="left" valign="top" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse !important;">
            <tr>
              <td width="20" rowspan="5" class="head-left-margin"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="9" align="left" valign="top" class="nd-bandeau-left-top-cell" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; font-size: 9px; line-height: 9px;">
                <img src="http://mywebsite/img/head-left-top.gif" width="205" height="9" alt="" class="nd-bandeau-left-top" style="display: block;" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="120" align="right" valign="bottom" class="nd-bandeau-titre-cell">
                <img src="http://mywebsite/img/titre-lettre.jpg" width="204" height="71" alt="La lettre de votre patrimoine" class="nd-bandeau-titre" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px;" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="44" align="left" valign="top" class="nd-bandeau-stitre-cell" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff;">
                N&deg;1 | Octobre 2015
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="13" align="left" valign="top" class="nd-bandeau-left-bottom-cell" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; font-size: 13px; line-height: 13px;">
                <img src="http://mywebsite/img/head-left-bottom.gif" width="205" height="13" alt="" class="nd-bandeau-left-bottom" style="display: block;" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td width="178" height="186" align="left" valign="middle" class="nd-bandeau-cell2">
          <img src="http://mywebsite/img/bandeau-left.jpg" width="178" height="186" alt="" style="display: block; background-color: #c3b9b1;" />
        </td>
        <td width="197" height="186" align="left" valign="middle" class="nd-bandeau-cell3">
          <img src="http://mywebsite/img/bandeau-right.jpg" width="197" height="186" alt="" style="display: block; background-color: #c3b9b1;" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I tried many fix, none worked: adding `line-height` to the cells that contains image with `mso-line-height-rule: exactly` before, collapsing HTML to remove any space, changing doctype... I'm a little out of ideas here, anyone have any clue of what is happenning here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong, and it was pretty trivial. The first row of my table (the one with `rowspan`) was missing a second cell - so the table layout was wrong.

Just by changing :

```
<tr>
  <td width="20" rowspan="5" class="head-left-margin"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td height="9" align="left" valign="top" class="nd-bandeau-left-top-cell">
    <img src="http://mywebsite/img/head-left-top.gif" width="205" height="9" alt="" class="nd-bandeau-left-top" style="display: block;" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

To :

```
<tr>
    <td width="20" rowspan="4" class="head-left-margin"> </td>
    <td height="9" align="left" valign="top" class="nd-bandeau-left-top-cell">
    <img src="http://mywebsite/img/head-left-top.gif" width="205" height="9" alt="" class="nd-bandeau-left-top" style="display: block;" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Fixed the issue. After that I still had one pixel vertical spacing after my images that are in cells with height < 15px. Thanks to zazzyzeph answer, I fixed it by changing the `line-height` and `font-size` to `0px` (setting the height of the image didn't worked for me) with `mso-line-height-rule`, adding `margin: 0` on the image and by collapsing the code to leave no space before/after the picture.

For example:

```
<td height="9" align="left" valign="top" class="nd-bandeau-left-top-cell" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;"><img src="http://mywebsite/img/head-left-top.gif" width="205" height="9" alt="" class="nd-bandeau-left-top" style="display: block;" /></td>
```

With all those fix my header now show perfectly on all email clients.

Comment: glad you got it working! If you can find a way to reconstruct the template without using that `font-size:0px` trick I'd recommend it: SpamAssassin (a pretty popular filter) will give you spam points for every instance. In this case it might be fine, but check http://isnotspam.com/

Comment: Very good to know, I wasn't aware of that. I just made a test on the website you linked, I have 3.9pts - it's a bit high but not considered as spam. I think I'll go with that for now as the newsletter has to be sent today, but I'll definitely keep that in mind for next time. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

it's because you have a cell (line 7) that is < 15px tall. Outlook 2007 and 13 will expand whatever cell you have that's under to 15.

a workaround:

```
<tr valign="bottom">
    <td height="9" style="font-size:9px; line-height:9px;">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
```

i usually get around doing that by using `padding-top` and bottom on `td`s (nesting tables where needed)

Comment: Hey and thanks for looking into that. That's what I already tried with no luck, I tried with `mso-line-height-rule` too, and set line-height / font-size for all cells, it didn't helped. I updated the code to reflect this.